# Any references on material for understanding fixed-income price discovery and occurrences of discrepancy in valuation between buy side/sell side?

Tags: fixed-income, trading

Can discrepancies in pricing occur for bonds between the buy-side and sell-side ask, in addition to other complex structured credit offerings like mortgage pools? My understanding is quoted yields and spreads on BBG are generally averages of transactions.  Why might these differences occur and how might one think about a final determinant for transaction price?

Comment: Do you have any example of situation or market that you are concerned with? Because as it is your question seems to me a bit wide and abstract.

Comment: Yields on t-bonds actually purchased in auction or a single corporate bond transaction between sell side and buy side traders? Not sure but from what I understand, the yield or price on executed deals may vary across similar transactions within the day